# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException in Java Based Configuration Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, spring-java-config

While I was using XML based configuration, I came across **java file based configuration**,when implemented I am facing issues in the code.

The project is just an example to understand the usage of Java Based Configuration file.

**Here is it's architecture:**

[image]

HelloWorld.java file is as follows :

```
public class HelloWorld {
 private String message;

   public void setMessage(String message){
      this.message  = message;
   }
   public void getMessage(){
      System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
   }
}
```

HelloWorldConfig.java files is as follows :

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfig {

  @Bean 
   public HelloWorld helloWorld(){
      return new HelloWorld();
   }
}
```

MainApp.java is as follows :

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ApplicationContext ctx = new 
      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HelloWorldConfig.class);

      HelloWorld helloWorld = ctx.getBean(HelloWorld.class);
      helloWorld.setMessage("Hello World!");
      helloWorld.getMessage();
    }
}
```

When I am running the MainApp.java as JavaApplication it results in following error :
[image]

Please help me in knowing what has been missed. Let me know if more information is required.

Comment: You are mixing jars from different versions of Spring. Never mix versions of jars from any framework that is trouble waiting to happen.

Comment: Also a good practice I would suggest - stop using default package. Create at least one package and put your classes there.

Comment: Two issues here. 1) You are using `JDK 11`    2) You are using a Spring version lesser than 5.1 that does not support JDK 11.   Solution: Either use JDK8 or lesser or Google another link with examples that uses a more up-to-date version of Spring

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks it worked.